# Structure as UserControl property

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, structure

This question is with VB2008 Express.

I'm making a usercontrol which uses a structured property.  Both the control and the overall project have an identical structure.  The problem is that within the main project, attempts to assign a place to this property results in: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

I have no clue what that means, nor how to deal with it.  Microsoft's help babbles something like: "You are referencing a non shared member, so an object reference will be required."

Well gee Microsoft, I read the error description so no shiznit... But what's that mean?  (I came from VB6 and I'm self-taught by example from there so please go easy on me.)

Of course I could assign each individual piece of the structure as its own property, such as "Street" "City", etc. but there are reasons I prefer to do it in one step, as it is validated all at once by the usercontrol upon assignment.

Any help getting my usercontrol and my main project to pass a "place" to each other?

```
   Public Structure Place
        Public PlaceName As String
        Public Street As String
        Public Apt As String
        Public City As String
        Public State As String
        Public Zip As String
        Public VerifiedStatus As Integer
        Public Lat As Single
        Public Lng As Single
    End Structure
    Public Property CurrentPlace() As Place
        Get
            Dim ThisPlace As New Place
            ThisPlace.Street = Trim(Me.txtStreet.Text)
            ThisPlace.Apt = Trim(txtAptNo.Text)
            ThisPlace.City = Trim(txtCity.Text)
            ThisPlace.State = Trim(lblState.Text)
            ThisPlace.Zip = Trim(txtZip.Text)
            ThisPlace.Lat = MyLat
            ThisPlace.Lng = MyLng
            ThisPlace.PlaceName = "" 
            'This control doesn't take placenames but they exist in the structure.
            ThisPlace.VerifiedStatus = MyVerifiedStatus
            Return ThisPlace
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Place)
            AsLoadedApt = Trim(value.Apt)
            AsLoadedCity = Trim(value.City)
            AsLoadedLat = value.Lat
            AsLoadedLng = value.Lng
            AsLoadedState = Trim(value.State)
            AsLoadedStreet = Trim(value.Street)
            AsLoadedVerifiedStatus = value.VerifiedStatus
            AsLoadedZip = Trim(value.Zip)
            txtStreet.Text = AsLoadedStreet
            txtAptNo.Text = AsLoadedApt
            txtCity.Text = AsLoadedCity
            lblState.Text = AsLoadedState
            txtZip.Text = AsLoadedState
            MyVerifiedStatus = AsLoadedVerifiedStatus
            MyLat = AsLoadedLat
            MyLng = AsLoadedLng
            Call ShowStatus()
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: (removed old comments that weren't pertinent to answering the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your structure inside the control and the usercontrol file as part of the project, the structure will be exposed as a type by qualifying it as part of the usercontrol:

```
Dim NewPlace As New UserControl1.Place
```

Now since you're using the same structure, the NewPlace object can be used to set the CurrentPlace property

```
    With NewPlace
        .Apt = "Apt"
        .City = "City"
        .Lat = 0
        .Lng = 0
        .State = "State"
        .Street = "Street"
        .Zip = "Zip"
    End With
    UserControl11.CurrentPlace = NewPlace
```

If it's part of a different project in the same solution add the qualification for the project as well.

Comment: That did it.  Wish it wasn't so code intensive, as I already have a place with all its "elements" (or are they called properties?) defined.  Essentially to use this approach, I have to assign the value of each element of one structure to the corresponding values of another structure, and then assign NewPlace to the property CurrentPlace.  I had hoped a one-liner would do it when both structures are identical.

Comment: Use search and replace to replace everywhere you instantiate a new structure with the type from the control.  Or you might be able to use inheritance, though I'm not too sure how that works with structures